# Raspberry Pi Windows GPIO Control

Tags: raspbian, gpio, windows

I installed Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi development board. I will read/write by specifying input/output from Raspberry Pi GPIO pins. I know on Raspbian OS but I haven't done it with Windows before. Can I control the GPIO pins? In what ways can I do it?

Raspberry Pi -> RPi 3

**Windows10 Professional**

https://uup.rg-adguard.net/

**Config**
[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10?  Which Pi?  I suggest you ask where  you downloaded  Windows 10 from.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: That is  a standard Windows OS.  I would ask on a  Windows forum as  accessing the GPIO will likely be  the same regardless of the target hardware.